# MVVM C#6 RelayCommand auto or expression-bodied properties

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, c#-6.0

I'm moving my project to C#6 and Visual Studio 2015 and I'm looking into improving my code to the newest features of Roselyn.

Current code:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    MyCommand = new RelayCommand(OnExecute, CanExecute);
}

public ICommand MyCommand { get; private set; }
```

Auto-properties

```
public ICommand MyCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand(OnExecute, CanExecute);
```

Expression-bodied properties

```
public ICommand MyCommand => new RelayCommand(OnExecute, CanExecute);
```

The auto-properties don't compile, because the `OnExecute` and `CanExecute` methods need to be static for that and I need to access private members in my viewmodel in these methods.

The expression-bodied implementation works, but for every call \ databind to the `MyCommand` property a new RelayCommand is created. And that also doesn't seem right to me.

Anybody has any ideas how to incorporate C#6 with RelayCommands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the best what you can achieve here with C# 6 features:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    MyCommand = new RelayCommand(OnExecute, CanExecute);
}

public ICommand MyCommand { get; }
```

the only difference from you original C# 5 code is, that you are now able to remove the property private setter, what makes it trully readonly. You won't be able to change it's value from codebehind anywhere once the object is constructed. It's very helpful when designing immutable objects.

**EDIT:**
on more approach, that works, but its readability is controversial. Advantage is that you don't have to navigate to ctor in order to find command instantiation.

```
private ICommand _myCommand;
public ICommand MyCommand => _myCommand ?? (_myCommand = new RelayCommand(Execute));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example of Expression-bodied properties looks alright.

```
public ICommand MyCommand => new RelayCommand(OnExecute, CanExecute);
```

Old style was

```
public ICommand MyCommand
{
    get { return new RelayCommand(OnExecute, CanExecute); }
}
```

AFAIK Expression-bodied properties are just syntactic sugar. 
The => susbtitutes the curly brackets and keywords get{ return }

That every call to databind creates a new RelayCommand is the standard way.

Comment: I don't agree with statement 'every call to databind creates a new RelayCommand is the standard and intended way'. It's neither standard nor intended - at least I cannot see why anyone would intend it. Does not make sense to me

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030 There you can check some documentation about RelayCommand. You can implement a RelayCommand as singleton but is not standard

Comment: I'm not talking about singleton, it would be nonsense, of course. In the article is opposite to what you said. There's command created only once and assigned to property's backing field.. Imagine what would happen if you did something like this: `MyCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();` (DelegateCommand from PRISM.MVVM). Also the example from article regarding commandviewmodel would be problematic with your apprpach

Comment: @Liero I'm not sure we understand each other. I think if you have {n} buttons binding to same command, {n} relaycommands will be created if there isn't a singleton check. Since it caused confusion I should edit the answer, any suggestion?

Comment: Imho, singleton means, that you can create only one intance of RelayCommand, but I suggest to create as many RelayCommand instances as many commands we need to define. Anyway, my concern is still the same - Expression-bodied properties are not suitable for this, because it won't work with many ICommand implementation, e.g mentioned DelegateCommand. You would call RaiseCanExecuteChanged on another instance than UI is binded to.

Comment: As Liero said the implementation with expression-bodied (relay\delegate)commands won't support RaiseCanExecuteChanged, because your UI will be bound to a different instance of that command. Maybe I will have a look at creating some kind of CommandFactory that keeps track of created instances so I can write `public ICommand MyCommand => CommandFactory.Create(OnExecute, CanExecute)`

Comment: @NiekJannink: Is the command factory worth it? I mean, when it comes to productivity, I use my own code snippet for commands. I only need to type command name, press enter, enter and all the stuff is generated for me. When it comes to readability, it is questionable - CommandFactory hides some details and nobody knows what exactly it does until you look at the implementation...

Comment: A second reason why I use the CommandFactory is to hide the implementation details from every view model about which kind of Command is used DelegateCommand, RelayCommand or whatever. That way it is easier to switch to a different Mvvm framework if required.